# PostgreSQL to Kafka replication using Pglogical

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-aurora, postgresql-10, logical-replication, pglogical

Can we setup PostgreSQL to Kafka replication using Pglogical?
Please share steps if possible.

Note- We are using AWS RDS and Aurora for PostgreSQL.
Thanks,